# Extract rules from RDF file using Sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, rules

This is the rule i want to extract in [RDF/XML](http://dbpedia.org/resource/RDF/XML) format :

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/myCompany/ontologies#x">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#Variable"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <swrla:isRuleEnabled rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">true</swrla:isRuleEnabled>
    <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">testing a rule</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TEST</rdfs:label>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#Imp"/>
    <swrl:body>
        <rdf:Description>
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList"/>
            <rdf:first>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#ClassAtom"/>
                    <swrl:classPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/myCompany/ontologies#depth"/>
                    <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/myCompany/ontologies#x"/>
                </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:first>
            <rdf:rest>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList"/>
                    <rdf:first>
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#BuiltinAtom"/>
                            <swrl:builtin rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#greaterThan"/>
                            <swrl:arguments>
                                <rdf:Description>
                                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List"/>
                                    <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int">2</rdf:first>
                                    <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
                                </rdf:Description>
                            </swrl:arguments>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </rdf:first>
                    <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
                </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:rest>
        </rdf:Description>
    </swrl:body>
    <swrl:head>
        <rdf:Description>
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList"/>
            <rdf:first>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#ClassAtom"/>
                    <swrl:classPredicate rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/myCompany/ontologies#profondeur"/>
                    <swrl:argument1 rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/myCompany/ontologies#Bad"/>
                </rdf:Description>
            </rdf:first>
            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
        </rdf:Description>
    </swrl:head>
</rdf:Description>
```

I'm wondering if i can extract a rule with a syntax more like :

```
depth(?x) ^ swrlb:greaterThan(2) -> profondeur(Bad)
```

Also, i don't want to use my rule inside protégé or an other software, i looking for an external connector like Jena or Pellet

Waiting for your responses,

Aloïs, a Sparql user.

Comment: What software are you using now? How are you "extracting" the rule you quoted? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance in improving your question, so you may get better answers.

Comment: Currently i'm using protégé to create my rules. Then i save my "ontology" in RDF format and i do Sparql query with Jena.
Right now i want to convert the RDF syntaxe to something that i can use in algorithme (in python or java for example).
Hope that help you a bit more to understand what i'm looking for.

Comment: Use OWL API which has native objects representing SWRL rules - in fact they are also modelled as OWLAxiom: `Set<SWRLRule> rules = ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SWRL_Rule);` with `ontology` being the `OWLOntology` object that represents the ontology

Comment: Note -- the "RDF format" you're saving to is actually the **RDF/XML** serialization of RDF. RDF may be serialized in many forms including RDF/XML, Turtle, N-Triples, N-Quads, TriG, and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, i finally managed to write some code with the OWL API

```
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        try {
            OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(ONTOLOGY_FILE_NAME));
            Set<SWRLRule> rules = ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SWRL_RULE);
            for (SWRLRule r : rules) {
                // body
                for (SWRLAtom a : r.getBody()) {
                    System.out.println(a.getPredicate().toString());
                    for (SWRLArgument ar : a.getAllArguments()) {
                        System.out.println(ar.toString());
                    }
                }

                // head
                for (SWRLAtom a : r.getHead()) {
                    System.out.println(a.getPredicate().toString());
                    for (SWRLArgument ar : a.getAllArguments()) {
                        System.out.println(ar.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```